# * operator, shell script

Tags: shell, bc

I've got problem with * operator.
I've tried to write a script, that take 3 paremater, first two are number (any type), the third is operator then print out result of the expression.
Everything've work fine except with * operator. 
I've got error
"(standard_in) 1: syntax error"

Here's my code.

```
if [[ $3 == / &&  $2 == 0 ]]
then
    echo "divide by 0"
    exit 1
fi
result=$(echo "$1$3$2"|bc -l)
echo "result: $result"
```

I print '$3' and got list file of parent directory, so the script understand that '*' is the list file.

So, what can i do with this issue?
Thank,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the asterisk as a string with `./myscript '*'` - in that case it's not expanded by your shell.

Comment: You're totally right… My fault. I removed the brackets of my answer. Thanks!